# pandas: How to set the values of a column with incremental values?

Tags: python, pandas

What is the easiest way to set a value in a column and to increment it for each match ? In the following example, I want to replace the first nan by 21, the second by 22, etc. For the moment, I do it this way but I'm sure that there is a more efficient way to do it.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':  [0,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],'b': [1,2,3,4]})
df
Out[29]: 
     a  b
0  0.0  1
1  NaN  2
2  NaN  3
3  NaN  4

new_values = []
start_val = 21
for i in df['a']:
    if np.isnan(i):
        new_values.append(start_val)
        start_val+=1
    else:
        new_values.append(i)
df['a'] = new_values
df
Out[30]: 
      a  b
0   0.0  1
1  21.0  2
2  22.0  3
3  23.0  4
```

Comment: Can you give some more information? Do you have one set of contiguous nulls, or are can they be separated? How should that be handled? I.e. is each group filled starting at 21, or is it just a counter from 21 up no matter what?

Comment: @ALollz There can be 0 nulls, 1 null, several ones or only nulls. Therefore, they can be separated or not. In the two cases, I want consecutive numbers (no repetition in the column). WeNYoBen's answer works as I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case

```
df.a=df.a.fillna(21+(df.a.isnull().cumsum()-1))
Out[121]: 
0     0.0
1    21.0
2    22.0
3    23.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```